# emachines e725 display very light

Tags: drivers, display

After hard installation of Ubuntu 12.04 alongside Windows 8 the display light is very high. How can I reduce it. I used <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>right</kbd> or left arrow but nothing changed. I am new in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

There is a program called Brightness and Lock. Open your dash using the windows key and type brightness. In that program you can use a slider to adjust the brightness of your screen.

Comment: There is no such thing as a brightness slider in the Brightness and Lock settings in Ubuntu 11.04 or newer.

Comment: yes I know I can use (Fn +Arrows) also and the slider changed its position but with no effect. And all circles on screen seem as ellipse. I can say the problem is in the display driver. I am new in Ubuntu. About 3 days usage.